# How do I link my UIButton to a line of code inside my didFinishLaunching?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want my button to restart my view when clicked, so when I click on it I want to run the following line of code:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
```

or would I want it to run my entire didFinishLaunching method?

How do I link the button ?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to reload your view?? Then you can use `[yourViewController.view setNeedsDisplay]`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by

> reload my app when clicked

but for doing anything on buttonClick
you will have to create an action for the button

```
 [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)buttonClicked
{
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewController animated:YES];
}
```

and explicitly calling `didFinishLaunching` is not the right and recommended way to do it.

You can make a method that contains all the `didFinishLaunching` code and call that method on ButtonClick

to access an `AppDelegate` Method from another `viewController` use

```
-(void)buttonClicked
{
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   [appDelegate methodToCall];
}
```

Comment: Hi, where would this line of code go? [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: you can add it in the `viewDidLoad` of the view controller containing the Button

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.viewController animated:YES] (which is in my viewController) results in an error saying viewController is not something in a structure or union, even though viewController is a property in my appDelegate.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: why are you trying to push self.??

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using private API's, it's not possible to restart your app.